# Do I need Autoloader-Class in PHP always?

Tags: php, autoloader, psr-4

I just start learning `MVC` in PHP, so my Question is

if I use `PSR-4` for Autoload, why should I create `Autoloader-Class` or don't I need it anymore?

Comment: You still need one. Most people use Composer nowadays which installs one for you when you use it.

Comment: But Composer does that and not i'm?

Comment: It can. I don't know if you're using composer, or if you're properly including it in your app, but generally if you're using composer, you don't need to write your own. Just read the Composer documentation.

Comment: Perfect. thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSR-4 is a specification that defines how to name your files and how autoloaders should load those files, so anyone can write "PSR-4 compliant" code and "PSR-4 compliant autoloaders" and they will work together, without having to reinvent the wheel for every individual library. Yes, you will still need an autoloader. PHP doesn't do autoloading out of the box, and just structuring your files according to PSR-4 doesn't make them autoload automagically.

The status quo is to use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to manage your dependencies, which comes with an autoloader which you can use. Or you use any other library management technique you want and any other autoloader you want, 3rd party library or one you have written yourself.

The alternative (to autoloading in general) is to write individual `require_once ...` statements, but that's a bit mad in this day and age and a bit of an unnecessary headache.